# Calling CoffeeScript method defined in another file form within an erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb

Shouldn't I be able to call this CoffeeScript method from within an erb template? It's not working but it seems like it should.

setup.js.coffee

```
class SetupStepTwo

  include @

  constructor: ->
    @resetView()

  resetView : ->
    console.log('cool');

window.ns1.SetupStepTwo = SetupStepTwo

$ ->
  new SetupStepTwo()
```

update.js.erb

```
window.ns1.SetupStepTwo.resetView();
```

Comment: I think this should work in theory. Your example won't run though because of that `include @` line. Is `include` defined elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I define 'include' elsewhere. That's not causing any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SetupStepTwo` class has an *instance* method called `resetView` but you're trying to call it as a *class* method (or at least what passes as a class method in (Java|Coffee)Script) when you say this:

```
window.ns1.SetupStepTwo.resetView();
```

If you really want to use `resetView` as a class method then your class should look more like this:

```
class SetupStepTwo
  constructor: ->
    @constructor.resetView()

  @resetView : ->
    console.log('cool')
```

The `@` on `@resetView` makes a class method and `@constructor` is, more or less, like `self.class` in Ruby.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eDdmd/

If you want `resetView` to be an instance method then you'll need to replace this:

```
window.ns1.SetupStepTwo.resetView();
```

with a `resetView` call on an instance of `SetupStepTwo`.